# XCode 4.2 stop interface builder auto zooming

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

Is there any way to stop IB in XCode 4 from zooming to try to fill the screen whenever I change the selected control? Trying to develop an iPad storyboard on a 1440x900 laptop screen is driving me crazy. It's making it nearly impossible to position large blocks on the screen.

Does anyone know of some hidden preference to force XCode to stop being so 'helpful'?

Thanks

Comment: Probably not possible, as the zoomed view is the only way to interact with controls.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alright, I've been working on trying to figure this out for you on and off for the past couple of days, digging through Xcode's guts and all, and I'm sorry to say I really don't think this is possible. The closest alternative that I think would work would be to use keyboard shortcuts to immediately zoom yourself back out after the auto zoom in :(

At least you can customize them![image]

Comment: An answer! And it's a decent workaround. Thank you very much MDT. Have a +1 and an accept. I ended up 'solving' the problem by buying a new laptop with a higher-res screen; your solution is quite a bit cheaper... (Although that's not the only reason I bought the laptop of course.)

Comment: My method may be cheaper, but yours is better. Now you have a new laptop!