# Turn off auto zoom in storyboard

Tags: xcode4.3

When editing a storyboard in Xcode 4.3, when I select an element, either by double clicking on the item (such as a button) in the view or selecting from the list on the left of the storyboard, Xcode pans to the element and zooms in so much that I cannot see most of the view.  This makes it very difficult to do much of anything.  Is there a way to disable this zoom 'feature'?

Comment: Have same issue, Xcode 6.2, Nice Job Apple !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but through answering a similar question, I found out that this in fact, is not possible. See link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9563917/716216